# Blazor Server-Side: How to use ClaimsPrincipal in Service-Class

Tags: blazor-server-side

I do some selects on a database with the Username like this:

```
private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _User;
public PrinterService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
                _User = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        }
public Task<PrinterLabel> GetDefaultPrinterLabelsAsync()
    {
        PrinterLabel printerLabel = new PrinterLabel();

        if (_User != null)
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteDBContext())
            {
                var uPL = db.UserPrinterLabel.Include(p => p.PrinterLabel).Where(u => u.UserId == _User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (uPL != null)
                    printerLabel = uPL.PrinterLabel;

            }

            if (printerLabel != null)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(printerLabel);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

When i run it with Visual Studio everything works. But when i deploy it to IIS. httpContextAccessor is not set to an instance.

I read something that i should not use IHttpContextAccessor. But how can i use ClaimsPrincipal without using IHttpContextAccessor?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found now this:
Blazor IHttpContextAccessor not working on IIS server #14878
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14878

i think i have to do it by another way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inject HttpContextAccessor to services?

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

or

```
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: Yes i use  services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); I tried now this services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); but still the same.